# Working XSLT code for XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I got an online XML-file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<klantenvertellen>
    <statistieken>
        <gemiddelde>8,7</gemiddelde>
        <aantalbeoordelingen>93</aantalbeoordelingen>
        <percentageaanbeveling>100</percentageaanbeveling>
        <gemiddelden>
            <cijfer name="Totaal oordeel">8,6</cijfer>
            <cijfer name="Prijs">7,7</cijfer>
            <cijfer name="Kwaliteit">8,7</cijfer>
        </gemiddelden>
    </statistieken>
    <resultaten>
        <resultaat>
            <antwoord name="datum">02-12-2015</antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Voornaam">
                <![CDATA[Marja]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="uit:">
                <![CDATA[Eindhoven]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Aanbeveling:">
                <![CDATA[ja]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Positieve ervaring:">
                <![CDATA[afspraak keurig nagekomen]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Totaal oordeel">8,0</antwoord>
        </resultaat>
        <resultaat>
            <antwoord name="datum">16-11-2015</antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Voornaam">
                <![CDATA[Erik]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="uit:">
                <![CDATA[Rotterdam]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Aanbeveling:">
                <![CDATA[ja]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Totaal oordeel">9,0</antwoord>
        </resultaat>
        <resultaat>
            <antwoord name="datum">13-11-2015</antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Voornaam">
                <![CDATA[Aad]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="uit:">
                <![CDATA[Schiedam]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Aanbeveling:">
                <![CDATA[ja]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Positieve ervaring:">
                <![CDATA[Keurig op tijd, netjes alles ingepakt, prima personeel.<br />
                    PERFECT.Het is de prijs zeker waard!]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Negatieve ervaring:">
                <![CDATA[Helaas staat mijn electrisch bedienbaar bed achterstevoren!!!<br />
                    Als ik wil lezen moet in aan het voeteneind gaan liggen!!!<br />
                    Hoe krijg ik dat zware bed omgedraaid in mijn eentje??]]>
            </antwoord>
            <antwoord name="Totaal oordeel">8,0</antwoord>
        </resultaat>
    </resultaten>
</klantenvertellen>
```

I want to retrieve the tags *antwoord* with name *'Voornaam'* and *'uit:'* but I cannot get an XSLT file to work.
For example, I tried this, but this also doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Voornaam</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">uit:</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="klantenvertellen/resultaten/resultaat">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="klantenvertellen/resultaten/resultaat/antwoord[name='Voornaam']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="klantenvertellen/resultaten/resultaat/antwoord[name='uit:']"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Heeeeelp!!

Comment: "*Now I have to filter out the empty tags...*" What empty tags?

Comment: When you've found a solution yourself, you should post it as an answer and mark it as accepted. First of all the question is marked as "finished" and second you might get the [self-learner badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner)

Comment: Not all people left a reaction, so some results (antwoord[@name='Positieve ervaring:']) contain no data. I would like to skip these entries...

Comment: You should edit your example to include such case and show the expected result. As it is, I can only guess you want do: `<xsl:for-each select="klantenvertellen/resultaten/resultaat[string(antwoord[@name='Positieve ervaring:'])]">`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something. This seems to work ok:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th style="text-align:left">Datum</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Voornaam</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">uit:</th>
        <th style="text-align:left">Reactie</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="klantenvertellen/resultaten/resultaat">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="antwoord[@name='datum']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="antwoord[@name='Voornaam']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="antwoord[@name='uit:']"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="antwoord[@name='Positieve ervaring:']"/></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I have to filter out the empty tags...